# Is it possible to configure a csproj file to allow any project item type?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a unique project in that I would like to be able to have CSHTML Razor Views, Windows Forms, and various other "non project type crossing" project item templates in one single project in visual studio.

Is there a way I can override the project type so that it compiles as a Windows Form's project but still allows me to add CSHTML files and other template types to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you edit the .csproj using notepad or an xml editor you'll find that `<ProjectTypeGuids>` element.

You can then edit it to have an entry like below

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Note: these are Guids from a portable class library project. You need to find correct ProjectTypeGuids for your requirements and add it.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d9d05cdc-96a1-4044-95d8-a4f8885a660a/what-is-the-significance-of-projecttypeguids-tag-in-the-visual-studio-project-file?forum=vsx